# Controlling simulink model through python, Getting 'None' values in output variables

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, variables, simulink, workspace

I would like to control my simulink model through the Python. My simulink model looks like the picture shown below. My simulink model has a name 'ToyExample_V2'

[image]

I want to give '1' as an input value to the constant block and I would like to run the simulation for 10 seconds with the timestep value 0.1.

To do this task, I have written below code.

```
import matlab.engine

class SimulinkPlant:
    def __init__(self, modelName='ToyExample_V2'):
        self.modelName = modelName
        self.eng = None
    
    def setControlAction(self, Input):
        # Set the input value in the Simulink model
        self.eng.set_param('{}/Input'.format(self.modelName), 'value', str(Input), nargout=0)
    
    def connectToMatlab(self):
        print("Starting Matlab")
        self.eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
        print("Connected to Matlab")
        
        # Load the model
        self.eng.eval("model = '{}'".format(self.modelName), nargout=0)
        self.eng.eval("load_system(model)", nargout=0)
        
        # Set the input value to 2 in the Simulink model
        self.setControlAction(1)
        print("Initialized Model")
        
        # Set the simulation parameters
        self.eng.eval("set_param(model, 'StopTime', '10')", nargout=0)
        self.eng.eval("set_param(model, 'FixedStep', '0.1')", nargout=0)
        
        # Start the simulation and instantly pause
        self.eng.eval("set_param(model, 'SimulationCommand', 'start')", nargout=0)
        self.eng.eval("set_param(model, 'SimulationCommand', 'pause')", nargout=0)
        
    
    def simulate(self):
        # Control Loop
        while self.eng.get_param(self.modelName, 'SimulationStatus') not in ('stopped', 'terminating'):
            # Continue the simulation
            self.eng.eval("set_param(model, 'SimulationCommand', 'continue')", nargout=0)
            
    def getOutput(self):
        # simout=self.eng.workspace['out.simout']
        simout_S =self.eng.eval("out.simout", nargout=0)
        tout_T = self.eng.eval("out.tout", nargout=0)
        # tout = self.eng.workspace['out.tout']
        return simout_S, tout_T
    
    def disconnect(self):
        # Stop the simulation and close Matlab connection
        self.eng.eval("set_param(model, 'SimulationCommand', 'stop')", nargout=0)
        self.eng.quit()

# Instantiate the SimulinkPlant object
plant = SimulinkPlant(modelName="ToyExample_V2")

# Connect to Matlab and set input value, simulation time, and timestep
plant.connectToMatlab()

# Start simulation
plant.simulate()

outputSim, timeT = plant.getOutput()

print('Simulation Output')
print(outputSim)

print('Time')
print(timeT)

# Close connection to MATLAB
plant.disconnect()
```

However, after running this code, I am not getting any results in my output variables `outputSim` and `timeT`. I am getting '`None`' as result as below:

```
Starting Matlab
Connected to Matlab
Initialized Model

Simulation Output
None

Time
None
```

How can I get the result values in my output variables?